# Pejorative terms for children or teenagers using the Internet

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, offensive-language, pejorative-language, internet

In Poland we have got many names for young children or teenagers using the Internet. For example we could see on the Internet that many have mangled the mother tongue and have been writing like this:

> I’m CoOl, dON’t yOu ThInK :***** swEEt

The point is that they mix capitalized and normal letters. We call these people pokémons.
I can see that this way of typing is also spread around the world so what do you call such people?

Second issue. Spotty teenagers flooding the web, asking over and over what had been answered, disregarding net etiquette. Someone forged the term of ‘neo child’. neo stem from the name of the product — Neostrada — a broadband Internet from the largest Internet provider in Poland: Telekomunikacja. Neostrada was and probably has been the most popular way to connect to the Internet so in some period of time we experienced such neo children.

Please watch this YouTube video to better understand what I mean:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6DZOq2hulk
(hope you like it :D)

So, do you have a name for such stupid behaviours? Ah, what is more interesting is that not only children can be called ‘neo’. Adults can too if only their behaviour is similar.

Comment: Is the the second different than trolling?

Comment: I think the word "teenagers" tends to come loaded with all forms of warning for the knowing.

Comment: In China, we call a similar phenomenon to the former _Mars Language_ (火星文). E.g. 煋 instead of 火星.

Comment: timur: sometimes they overlap. Often being a troll you have to be intelligent to instigate a war.

Comment: For the *phenomenon* (rather than the kids), there's also the phrase "Eternal September". (Look it up.)

Answer (score 6):

There's no specific term I know of that is used to describe adolescent people on The Internet. Here are some specific terms:

- *Script kiddie* refers to people who use scripts to attack computer systems. They are referred to in a derogatory manner as 'kiddies' (a slag term for 'kids' or 'children') because they typically do not have the skill to write the scripts on their own and have obtained them from another source and run them. They are often stereotyped as writing in the style you described (alternating case).
- *newbie/noob/newb/nub* refers to any person who is new to the activity in which they are participating. You can modify the adjective with a noun to specify the activity explicitly: an *internet newb* is someone who is new at using the Internet.
- *Troll* refers to any person on the internet who posts inflammatory content for the purpose of enticing anger or other negative emotions from people. They are often stereotyped as being younger people.

Comment: Once everybody was a newbie so I don’t find it especially bad name. But I've often seen that they call themselves a ‘n00b’ (recanting or self-whipping): ‘hey I’m n00b, help please!’. The point is that to RTFM which neo children don’t.

Comment: As I’m not a native I can’t see much difference between nub/n00b. But you’re right: I think I could use nub or kiddie.

Comment: I was under the impression that trolls were all ages, and if anything, older.